# How can i make cloth details like this?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

I've been trying to create some cloth for weapons for a while now but they always end up looking really flat or weird, how can i make something like this?

[image]

Usually i try to add a plane or use the cloth simulator, but both look really bad, how can i make cloth details like this one where it's falling of the sword? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems like this typically occur when your cloth mass is too light.
Try to give it higher mass value, then do a simple animation that just lets the cloth fall down naturally then try to render some good middle frame that looks good.

Also, check you gave it enough subdivisions in edit mode.

And if you are doing an animation make sure you set the cloth collision and self collision and up their qualities.

[image]